# How can I 'git clone' from another machine?

Tags: git, git-clone

On one machine (IP address 192.168.1.2), I create a Git repository by

```
$ cd /home/hap/working
$ git init
$ (add some files)
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

And I have another machine on the same Wi-Fi network. How can I get clone from the other machine?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You need to use a git+ssh [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to perform the Git cloning:

```
git clone git+ssh://hap@192.168.1.2/~/working
```

To break it down:

- `git+ssh` tells Git that you want to use ssh to connect to the Git repository.
- `hap` is your username (I assume based on the home directory in your question).
- `192.168.1.2` is the machine that you want to connect to
- `~/working` is the path to your Git repository on the remote machine (so `~` is your home directory)

Some other things to note:

- You need to have a ssh server enabled on the machine with the Git repository
- You'll need to know the password for the user `hap`

Comment: I don't think `git+ssh://` is needed. You should be able to simply use `hap@192.168.1.2:~/working`. Also cloning directly from a working directory sets the clone up to push into that working repo, which should be avoided.

Comment: This can be useful, for instance if you are working on machine X which can't access remote repo but can access another local machine that has access to remote. In my case I am using this where i develop on a linux machine with no access to the vpn needed to go straight to the remote.

Comment: Is it as easy to clone using a certificate?

Comment: what if the path of Git repository is not on the home directory? i.e `E://folder/working` what would i change to `~/working`?

Comment: I made use of `git clone git+ssh://..' because my use case is similar to @Matt Wolfe. The feature works fine for me on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 4):

I think people are looking for this answer. The following command in the terminal wil login into the other computer and clone an existing repo. In the current path location of the terminal (so `cd` to the preferred location first).

```
git clone username@12.345.67.891:/home/path/to/repo.git
```

In case you do not now the IP address. Use ping to determine the ip of your server. After the IP address don't forget to use the use a `:` and then write the absolute path.

Comment: Why `sudo`, why server ? op asked specifically between two systems on a network, supposedly to save bandwidth ... this does not at all answer the question and is plain incorrect.

Comment: @thecarpy you are right when I read it back it has little to do with the exact question.

Comment: @Michiel how to provide password?

Comment: @AshokSri This is a bit late, but when using this it should just prompt you for your password.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that on both machines you have installed Git.

Now what you do depends on what services you have installed, that is, how you can connect from one machine to the other.

The simplest case is when you have `sshd` running on the machine you want to clone *from*, and you can ssh from the machine you want to clone *to* to the machine you want to clone from.

If you can do

```
ssh 192.168.1.2
```

(or if you have different username on the other machine, `ssh user@192.168.1.2`), then you should be able to clone via SSH, like [Josiah wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808177/how-can-i-git-clone-from-another-machine/2808221#2808221):

```
git clone git+ssh://hap@192.168.1.2/~/working
```

If you want to continue to fetch / push between machines, you should configure public key authentication for SSH, to not have to provide password on each fetch.

---

If you don't have sshd installed on the source machine, you can clone using "smart" HTTP protocol if you have a web server installed and can install CGI scripts (see [git-http-backend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) manpage), or you can clone using "dumb" HTTP protocol if you have web server installed, but can only serve static files (you would need to run `git update-server-info` in source repository first), or you can clone using [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) if you have it installed.

As a last resort, you can use "[git bundle](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html)" to create an archive which you can move, for example, using a USB pendrive and clone from it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was ok with the following command.

```
git clone ssh://git@<ip address>/PATH/TO/REMOTE/REPO
```

Comment: How to provide password?