# Git - simplest way to sync a repository with a checked out branch

Tags: git

My workflow is basically:

- Create a repo on my desktop PC
- Do some work on it and commit changes
- Clone onto my laptop
- Work on that, commit changes

Now I want to synchronise the changes with my desktop. Trying `git push desktop.local:~/my-repo` will fail, because [the master branch is already checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked-ou). I know of two solutions to this:

1. Create a third, bare repository in another directory on my PC and update both working copies from there. But a single central repository with two working copies checked out sounds like... SVN! Except clumsier, because I can't just use `svn update` and `svn commit` to synchronise with this central repository — extra steps are required to actually update the central repo from changes committed to a working copy in Git.
2. Push to a separate branch and merge that branch in on my desktop working copy. This isn't too bad, but...

...what I don't understand is this: if I just SSH to the desktop PC and issue `git pull laptop.local:~/my-repo`, it works! It pulls the committed changes in and updates the checked out master branch, no questions asked. Why can't `git push` do this itself?

So here's my question: is there a command that works the same as `ssh`-ing in to my desktop PC and issuing a `pull`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you are trying to push you are doing 2 actions at the same time.
The first one is to update git tree and the second one is to update the working directory on your laptop. So there is a kind of implicit 'checkout' in the push process and git refuse to do it and it's right.
Imagine what will happen if someone was actually working on your desktop PC.
When you do an SSH things are different,  you are in your working directory, you are responsible for everything you do, and so, can do what ever you want , removing file , "pulling". So it seems normal in a way, that pushing doesn't allow you (by default) to mess up the remote computer.

#### Update

If you are setting the receive.denyCurrentBranch to ignore , you can push but you still have to "synchronize" your working directory with the "latest" version of the code (the one you just pushed). That mean you still have 2 commands to run one on each computer

If you really want to run only one command use the power of the shell and create an alias which do a git pull from the Desktop computer

```
alias remote_pull=ssh <desktop> "cd <path>; git pull"
```

Comment: I sort of understand that, but my question is basically "is there a(nother) command (not necessarily `git push`) that does this?"

Comment: the command is `git push` and set as czchen suggested the receive.denyCurrentBranch on the server side. You have to do a checkout -f on the desktop side then which is dangerous. So as you have anyway to run one command on each side, I would recommand using a third repo.

Comment: Ah, this is what confused me: *"The first one is to update git tree and the second one is to update the working directory on your laptop."* ... I thought there might be a command to just update the git tree from another repo. I'll accept this, since "no" with a decent explanation is still an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to warn to allow pushing to your desktop PC. However, this is dangerous. If there are some commits in your desktop PC, this push will cause confuse.

The following is manual of `receive.denyCurrentBranch` for your reference.

```
  receive.denyCurrentBranch
      If set to true or "refuse", receive-pack will deny a ref update to
      the currently checked out branch of a non-bare repository. Such a
      push is potentially dangerous because it brings the HEAD out of
      sync with the index and working tree. If set to "warn", print a
      warning of such a push to stderr, but allow the push to proceed. If
      set to false or "ignore", allow such pushes with no message.
      Defaults to "refuse".
```

Comment: Would it have the same problems with `git pull` from the desktop, though (I haven't tried `pull`-ing with extra commits on the desktop)? I don't understand why it's seamless when I `pull`, but not when I `push`.