# How do I: Git One Way Push / Uneditable Working Directory?

Tags: git

Is there a way to have two machines, let's say A and B.

- A is my local machine, where I develop my code, and push it.
- B is a server, that will NEVER have to edit code, but NEEDS a working directory.

Is it possible to do this *without* doing any `git pull`'s whatsoever from B?

---

I want to use git one way only, basically. In one direction. Sort of like using `rsync` to sync a local directory to a remote one, but with version control. If this isn't possible with git, is it possible with anything else?

Again, preferably with version control.

Comment: You'll probably want to have B in a detached head state, so that you can push new code to B. Then with a post-receive hook, have B checkout the latest commit directly (not a branch, because you can't update a branch while it's currently checked-out without using `pull` or `merge`).

Comment: This may be of interest: [Git - simplest way to sync a repository with a checked out branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011089/git-simplest-way-to-sync-a-repository-with-a-checked-out-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) explains it very well.  I'll copy the code from there.

It assumes you have SSH authentication set up (no password) between your server and workstation.

On the server:

```
mkdir website.git && cd website.git
git init --bare
mkdir /var/www/www.example.org
touch hooks/post-receive
chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

Then put this in hooks/post-receive

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
```

---

In your local git repository:

```
git remote add web ssh://server.example.org/home/ams/website.git
git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

---

Configuration:

- **/var/www/www.example.org** is the public root of this site.
- **/home/ams** is the location you created website.git
- **server.example.org** is the domain, IP, or host alias of your server

Comment: hi thank you for this but i cant make it running. Got an error --

fatal: '~/website.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

hope you can help me on this. thanks

Comment: @andsien, perhaps you don't have SSH set up; or you're mixing up the commands that need to be run on the server, and the ones that need to be run on your computer.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. i already got it, i did not use the public root of my site.