# Deleting or undoing a push to a remote Git repo

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-remote

I created a remote git repository and proceeded to push code to it from the wrong local repo.
The local repo is fine I just want to remove the content I pushed to the remote and start over.

I have tried `git push origin :master` but got an error:

```
! [remote rejected] master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://.................
```

Is there a simple way of checking it in? 'check in' or 'checking in' (and other variations) produce no relevant results.

Comment: I need to explain this a little better
We are using Gerrit and have a Redhat Enterprise machine holding the remote repos for many projects. I have a couple of projects around a single system we are working with called lectopia.

Answer (score 2):

```
branch is currently checked out
```

That means your [remote repo isn't a bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked-ou) (i.e. a repository without any working tree, meaning a branch has been checked out). Plus that would remove the all `master` branch!

If you have access to the server where your remote repo is, you could reset the master branch to `HEAD~1` in order to [remove what has just been pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit) (assuming you are the only person to push to it).

If you haven't a direct access, you can go to a correct local repo and [force push that correct HEAD to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-to-delete-a-git-commit/1338744#1338744):

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

But I would also recommend [converting your remote repo to a bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked-ou/3251126#3251126).

Answer (score 1):

What you tried to do would delete the branch head, not the commits. Definitely not what you want.
However, deleting central commits is a BAD idea. Use "git revert" instead.