# does git amend require a git push -f?

Tags: git

```
make changes
git commit 'made changes' -a
git push origin
make more changes
git ammend -a
git push origin
```

I've noticed that when I do a `git commit --ammend -a` and then try to push to a remote repo, it requires that I force the push (`git push -f`).

My guess is because it's trying to push the same (?whats the word?) commit code  but notices differences in files.

Is this correct / normal?

Comment: There is no `git amend` command; are you referring to `git commit --amend`?

Comment: @MarcoLeogrande thanks made the change i'm too used to my aliases `>_<`

Comment: A little off topic, but I think that after you have pushed a commit, doing an amend on that commit is a bad idea.  Your commit is out there.  Accept it.  Create a new commit that includes the changes that you forgot to put in the original.  Then push that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `git commit --amend` or a `git commit --author=<author>`, if anything is modified, will generate a different SHA1.
Then, yes, a `git push -f` will be needed.

`git amend` can be defined as an alias like in this [blog post](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/git-amend):

```
git config --global alias.amend 'commit --amend -C HEAD'
```

> This alias adds a `git amend` command that will reuse the current commit message when it amend it.

Comment: See also, for additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10728453/6309. Beware of the danger of a `git push -f` though ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo

Comment: THanks @VonC just as I suspected. So is there any way to circumvent this or to know if it is safe to ignore it? (I can think to pull the remote locally and `git diff` ?)

Comment: @iight ignore the `push -f`? You won't be able, if you want to push back an *amended* commit (ie, the same content, with a different SHA1 because of an amended metadata information).