# How to change commit message in GitHub,please check the marked section

Tags: git, github

[image][image]

I am trying to edit this description on Github and cant find any edit button for this,I typed the description when I uploaded this project with GitHub Desktop.
Any suggestions on how to edit it?

I want that the commit message will be "A project based on the DAX index" 
as shown below.

I got to this screen what should I do now?

Comment: It looks like you want to edit the commit message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing the git commit message in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728420/editing-the-git-commit-message-in-github)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to change the commit message this is not a proper title for your question. this is already answer here :

[Editing the git commit message in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728420/editing-the-git-commit-message-in-github/41513487#41513487)

## GitHub's instructions for doing this:

1. On the command line, navigate to the repository that contains the commit you want to amend.
2. Type `git commit --amend` and press Enter.
3. In your text editor, edit the commit message and save the commit.
4. Use the `git push --force example-branch` command to force push over the old commit.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to rewrite history with git.

1. Use `git commit --amend` to change your latest log message.
2. Use `git commit --amend` to make modifications to the most recent commit.
3. Use `git rebase` to combine commits and modify history of a branch.
4. `git rebase -i` gives much more fine grained control over history modifications than a standard `git rebase`.

Source - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history