# How do i change "Add files via upload" on Github Repo?

Tags: github

[image]

As you can see, it say add files via upload. I wanted to change it to something like " created for database model". Does anyone know how? if so please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing the git commit message in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728420/editing-the-git-commit-message-in-github)

Comment: no i don't have command line, i want to do it manually on github , is there any possible way?

Comment: I am not aware, but the answer to the linked question suggests that it won't be possible.