# Heroku: pushing to an url created outside the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Normally, when I deploy to Heroku, I create the heroku app from within the Rails console with the command

```
heroku create mycustomappname
```

and then it creates that heroku url

```
http://mycustomappname.herokuapp.com
```

and then when I push to heroku, the app is available at that custom domain.

However, after creating a canvas app on Facebook, and selecting Heroku to host, Facebook gave me the heroku url.  I have a rails app on my local host. How do I push to that specific heroku url if it wasn't created from within the Rails console?

Comment: How about adding the heroku url as another remote in git and pushing to it?

Comment: thanks, would I put it as 'origin' like when I do it to github? "git remote add origin https//..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this from the console:

```
heroku git:remote -a <heroku url>
```

This will add a remote for the heroku url to your git config. See also [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Comment: Thanks, but I got an error. Do you happen to know how I would deal with this?  " To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again. "

Comment: @Michael -- You could force it via `git push -f` to force your changes through to heroku, then a `git pull`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-to-properly-force-a-git-push).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure out what I put after 'git pull'. Pull what? The name of the Heroku url?  Be grateful if you can assist. Note, I did the git push -f, and it worked, but now confused about the git pull

Comment: @Michael - `git pull` is the equivalent of `svn update` -- it pulls down the changes in the repository so that your local repo and the heroku repo are the same. It should be unnecessary in this case. Once you do a `git push` you should have forced your changes to the the heroku app. You should be good to go now.