# Trouble pushing to origin after local hard reset

Tags: git, push, git-reset

I recently did a hard reset of my local git repository: In other words I reset it to an earlier point in time. Now when I try to push up to the `origin` it tells me that it can't because the `origin` contains work of a later date than my repository. This makes sense, but I don't care about the work the origin has after my local repository.

If I first `pull`, which is what I am told to do, I presume that my local `HEAD` will then become whatever the `origin` `HEAD` was, i.e. with the additional work and my hard reset will be for nought.

How should I proceed here? To recap, I don't care about the additional later work on the origin, but do care about the extra work on the local done after the hard reset.

I am beginning to think that hard resets are not a great idea.

Comment: pull should do a fetch then a merge, so you should be ok.  worst case (if this doesn't work) is that you'd have to do the hard reset again.

Comment: @jdigital And after the hard reset he will face the same issue again ;)

Comment: @TimWolla right. i was trying to say that it's worth trying a `pull` because it won't make things any worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `push --force` to override the current `HEAD` of the `origin`, even if your local branch is not a descendant of it.

**However:** You should be aware of the consequences: Other developers working on the same repository now cannot easily pull in the changes, but have to reset / rebase to the origin. Using forced pushes / rewriting pushed history is *bad* and should be avoided whenever possible.

See also another answer here on StackOverflow on the dangers of forced pushes: [How to properly force a Git Push?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702355/782822)