# Xcode two master branches. Can't commit

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I'm having a little problem with Xcode.
As it looks like, I seem to have two Master Branches (working copies), which gives me problems when I'm trying to commit my changes.
I think I screwed up when starting the project. I had a ViewController and wanted to have a TableViewController. I deleted the whole project and started from scratch. Maybe not everything was gone. No idea. Help is appreciated!

The two Master Branches:
[image: The two Master Branches]

The problem with committing (About 15 files changed, but he only lets me save these:
[image: The problem with committing (About 15 files changed, but he only lets me save these...]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-to-properly-force-a-git-push

Comment: I'm not using Git. Only Xcode.

Comment: Still works (I think) Just run Git from Terminal.

Comment: Can't get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source control menu, hover over one of your branches, then select configure xxx branch. A dialog box will popup, Goto the Branches Tab, and inspect the date of the last modification, it it's the older one, delete it, if its not, try the other one.

Comment: Try deleting one of them with the little minus button on the lower left of the branches tab.