# Cant git push to master after revert

Tags: git, github, push, revert

I pushed my changes to my remote master branch by mistake. So to keep them safe I created a `backup` branch. I then reverted the changes I did to remote master.

On my local master branch I ran:

```
git revert <commit_sha>
```

and then

git push

I have now finished working on the new branch (backup) and it all looks good. But I can't push the changes from my local `backup` branch to remote master. When I run `git pull` on my backup branch the changes I made are lost. The code is replaced with the contents of the remote master.

Is there a way for me to push my changes to the remote master branch without losing my work?

Comment: *I checked out a new branch and pushed them there.* That doesn't make sense: you can check out a local branch, but you can't push to one. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: @Jubobs I think OP meant he created a "backup" branch and push that to his remote repo.

Comment: "*I then reverted the push I did to master*" also doesn't make much sense. Do you mean that you reverted the last commit in the local `master`, or that you force push to the remote `master` branch?

Comment: Sorry @Jubobs, I meant I created a backup branch and continued the work there as isim said

Comment: Also, please clarify "*all my changes are overwritten with master*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since you have already performed a `revert` on your local `master` branch and push it to your remote, you should just make all your new changes on your local `master` branch and forget about the `backup` branch. Keep in mind your `backup` branch still contains those erroneous codes from before. If you pushed it to your remote, you will introduce those codes you reverted out back.

**Original Answer**

If you are the [only person working on that remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702355/1144203), then you should be able to use

```
git push -f <remote> <branch>
```

to force push your new branch to your remote master branch.

To help out with the terminology a bit, every git repository has a local `master` branch. Hence, saying *I pushed my changes to master..* doesn't make sense. We either *push to remote (which by default is labeled as `origin`)* or *merge with (local) master*.

Comment: I'm not the only person working on the remote master branch, is there a safe way to do it?

Comment: @user3393708 If you're not the only person working on the remote branches, you should never rewrite history to begin with (by using `git revert`), unless you are absolutely 200% sure that no one has done a `git pull` since you pushed your unintended changes.

Comment: no one did git pull since I pushed the unintended changes

Comment: @user3393708 Actually, I was mistaken between `reset` and `revert`. If you used `revert`, then you won't have to worry about anyone has done a pull.

Comment: Since you have already reverted your mistakes on your local master branch, why can't you make your new changes there and forget about your backup branch?