# When using git filter-branch, it duplicates my commit history and creates duplicate files. How do I get rid of this?

Tags: git, github, version-control, sed, git-filter-branch

I accidentally committed a password in one of my files, so now i'm attempting to get rid of it.

The command I am running is:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/password/REDACTED/g' {} \;"`

It successfully does what I need it to do, but it duplicates all my files with a `.rb-e` extension, and also duplicates all my commits. How do get rid of the files, and prevent the duplication of my commits?

Comment: Are you, by chance, using MacOS X or a BSD?

Comment: @Wintermute Yes, sorry I should have noted that. I'm on OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed` that comes with MacOS X is BSD sed, not GNU sed, and <s>it cannot change files in place without making a backup - the</s> its `-i` flag always takes an argument that is the suffix the backup file will have. In your call, `-i -e` is parsed as one flag, telling sed to edit the file in place and put a backup in `filename-e`. That is the reason you get a lot of `.rb-e` files.

The most practical solution, I believe, is to just delete the backup files afterwards. That is,

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/password/REDACTED/g' {} \; -exec rm '{}'.bak \;"
```

I took the liberty of replacing `-e` with a more sensible filename extension (`.bak`). **Make sure to use a suffix that does not clash with files that you want to preserve.** You can put the `-e` back in there if you like, but it's not necessary in this case.

EDIT: @torek notes that BSD sed can edit files in place if its `-i` flag is given an empty string as argument (i.e., `''`); working mostly with GNU sed, I did not know that. Nevertheless, I feel that allowing sed to generate a backup file is better practice than using `-i ''`. In the above `find` call, the command in the second `-exec` will only be executed if the command in the first reported successful completion (because `-exec` is also a filter), so with it, you'll still have the backup file if sed comes back with an error. And when things go wahoonie-shaped, backups are nice to have.

Comment: Ok, this helped with all the duplicate files. I ran this on a test branch, and everything worked perfectly. However, when I ran it on my master branch, it duplicates my commit history and says i'm 53 commits ahead of my remote. I can understand this since `filter-branch` is iterating over all my previous commits, but is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Ah. Well, your local repo is now quite different from the remote, and rewriting remote history is rather deep in "this should never, ever happen" territory. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push (particularly at all the warnings).

Comment: So it's recommened to just push all 53 commits up to the remote, even though ONE word was changed in the entire `filter-branch` command? I feel that it's just a little unnecessary, but if it's best practice then I suppose I will just push it.

Comment: The word presumably remains changed in all those commits, so the states the commits describe is changed for all of them. Pushing just one is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a sed issue, not a git issue:

> -i *extension*
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified *extension*.  If a zero-length *extension* is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

You're giving the *extension* argument `-e`, and then a sed command without a `-e` flag (which is OK as long as there is only one command).

If you use `sed -i ''` this will provide a zero-length extension, but see the "not recommended" part of the above.