# Git Rebase Interactive

Tags: github

I'm trying to delete old github commits with the interactive rebase, but I don't know how to actually save the changes I've made and push them onto my repository. I haven't found anywhere that actually explains how to exit the interactive rebase, and keep your changes. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to *finish* the rebase instructions in your editor.

Exit your editor, and it should apply your changes.

If there are any conflicts while rebasing, you'll have to fix them, stage your changes and use `git rebase --continue`.

That's it. The rebase will finish itself.

Once you're done, you'll have to [force push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push) to overwrite the remote state of your branch.