# Forcing a Git/GitHub push from a disjointed local repo

Tags: git, github

I have a real mess on my hands. I have a private GitHub repo that I own and am the sole contributor/maintainer of. So whatever hackery is required to solve my problem will *only affect me and no one else.*

Here's my situation:

1. My GH repo is, say, `https://github.com/mygithubuser.example.com/myapp.git`. I have a local clone of `myapp` at, say, `~/sandbox/workspace/myapp`.
2. I deleted `~/sandbox/workspace/myapp/.git` (effectively disconnecting it from git/GitHub) and renamed it to `~/sandbox/workspace/myapp-old`.
3. I created a new barebones app project locally at `~/sandbox/workspace/myapp`.
4. Inside that *new* `myapp` dir, I did: (a) `git init`, (b) `git add .`, (c) `git commit -m "Starting over again."`.
5. I now want to somehow connect the new local `myapp` repo to my GitHub repo at `https://github.com/mygithubuser.example.com/myapp.git`, and completely blow out anything that is in that remote repo with everything that is in the new local `myapp` repo.

So again, I want to force GH to allow a push from my new `myapp` repo to override *everything* that is in my remote GH repo.

We have to pretend that `myapp-old`, although it exist locally on my machine, cannot be part of any solution. We have to pretend like it no longer exists.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610763/4009451) but it's not working for me. What can I do? What are the exact Git command-line invocations I can run to accomplish what I'm looking for?

---

Please note there *is* a specific reason for why I need to do exactly what I'm asking for here. To explain why would require me to launch into a very long backstory that would be dry, boring, and would make this question a strong candidate for downvoting/closevoting. So please don't ask me "Why are you doing this?"- or "Why don't you just X"! I promise you there is a good reason for it.

Comment: "but it's not working for me" -- That's exactly what should work just fine. You already managed to get it working some other way, so I suspect you won't want to spend more time on this, but for future questions, please be more specific, include the exact command-line you *did* use, and the output it gave you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping on this for a night, it just *dawned* on me (no pun intended) what the best solution is. Posting it here for any future git-newbs in the same dilemma.

1. Disconnect the new repo (`~/sandbox/workspace/myapp`) from Git (`rm -rf .git`)
2. Get the new repo working the way I want it
3. Rename the new repo (e.g. `mv ~/sandbox/workspace/myapp ~/sandbox/workspace/meh`)
4. Clone the GH repo to `myapp` (`git clone https://github.com/mygithubuser.example.com/myapp.git`), which yes, produces **yet another** `~/sandbox/workspace/myapp`, based on the old one
5. Copy changes over from `/meh` to `myapp`
6. Push
7. ...
8. Profit