# Git remove last commits from remote made by someone else

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

So, my situation is (by mistake) I have given access to a person to commit to my branch. Now in my local I have made a commit and when I tried to push it to the remote it shows that the remote is ahead. Because the other person has pushed his code to this branch with several commits. Now, can I remove those commits from remote without taking pull to my local?

I tried to do this `git push origin +<<commit number>>^:branch`

But it says `src refspec <<commit number>>^ does not match any.`

Comment: Why don't you `git push -f origin <<branch>> `. The `-f` will destroy the origin tree and replace it by your local one. If you do not want to force push, as fat as i know, you can't rebuilt the tree without pulling the modifications

Comment: Ok so I can do this without taking pull right?

Comment: Yes, this is a regular push (it just rewrite the commit tree)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this

```
git push origin <<branch_name>> -f
```

In this `-f` if used for force push

This will remove commits that are made by someone else.