# Git - deleted a remote file, how to restore

Tags: git

I have a local git, I made a commit (let's say my third commit), then I pushed to origin on a remote website.

I inadvertedly deleted a *remote* file, now I tried to push again with:

`git push origin master`

but it returns "`Everything up-to-date`"

I'm not sure I deleted other files, so how do I push to remote and "overwrite/add missing files" to last local commit.

Comment: To clarify, I think you mean: you deleted a file in your local repo, then committed and pushed that change?  And you want to revert that change?

Comment: Nope, I pushed a commit to a remote, then I went in the remote and deleted FROM THE REMOTE, the local is the good one.

Comment: Right ok.  You have a non-bare repo on the remote, and you're also able to make changes to it via the (remote) filesystem.  A force-push is probably the immediate fix.  But you should probably also consider avoiding this setup (to avoid future mishaps in future).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes, tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push origin <your_branch_name> --force`

Even though this can solve your problem. Be careful though as this is a dangerous command.

See explanation here: [How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push)

Comment: I get this: error: src refspec maser does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://...'

Comment: Seems you used `maser` instead of `master`

Comment: Gosh you are right. Ok I fixed the typo and I still get "Everything up-to-date" and the missing files still missing

Comment: To revert to a previous commit, ignoring any changes:

`git reset --hard HEAD`

Then try the force push. A last ditch effort, if you have a way to browse your files, on github or the github client, you can go to the `commits` tab and select a commit that you know has that file(s) and copy the contents over to a new file with same name in your local folder structure.

Comment: For some reason `git reset --hard HEAD` and than `force` again does not work

Comment: Can you try `git reset --hard` without the HEAD or to go back two commits and see if the file is there, `git reset HEAD~2` and make sure you run `git status` to see if the file is there.