# Git repo remote change folder

Tags: git, git-push

I created a git repository in folder A.
And then, I push it to a remote (let's say it's called D)
Then, I delete folder A, and create a new folder B with very different files/folders inside it.
And, I want to change the remote D so it's pointing to B.

How to do it? thanks

Comment: A force push?­­­

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+how+to+force+push

Comment: @iBug Sorry I'm not familiar with the term.. This question sounds more friendly to beginner, so I think it's better not to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Initialize a new git repository in B: `git init`
2. Add all files in B: `git add .`
3. Commit: `git commit -a -m "Initial commit"`
4. Add D as a remote `git remote add origin <D>`
5. Force push to D: `git push -fu origin master`

This will destroy the history on D, so beware and if some one else is referring to that remote it might piss them off.