# overwrite current origin master branch with older local master branch

Tags: git

I cloned a repository via

`git clone repoUrl`

Next I wanted to roll back to a specific commit id via

`git reset commitId`

After reverting the local changes I have a clean master branch. When running

`git status`

it says

> Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 21 commits, and can be
> fast-forwarded.

Is it fine to make new local commits now? What will happen when I push the changes to the origin repo? Will it completely overwrite the master branch from the origin (I want that) or will it somehow try to merge the local master branch and the origin master branch.

I want to completely remove the most recent 21 commits and start new from an older commit.

Comment: Is anyone else using the master branch? If not, you can just force push over it.

Comment: so `git push --force` will completely overwrite it without merging?

Comment: Yes, but if you have any collaborators that will cause problems. Use with caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have the right to rewrite the history of the branch in the remote repository unless you have the push force right.
It's not advised unless you know exactly what you're doing (you can still revert all the 21 commits instead so that you can still see them in the history).

If you still want to proceed, you can look at the following link :
[How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push)