# GIT/GITHUB/NEXTJS

Tags: git, github

I have a nextjs project and I want to push the changes to a private repository. The problem is after I write `git push --force  origin main`

I get:

> Enumerating objects: 15502, done.
> Counting objects: 100% (15502/15502), done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads
> Compressing objects: 100% (10926/10926), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (15502/15502), 298.04 MiB | 4.02 MiB/s, done.
> Total 15502 (delta 4468), reused 14796 (delta 4057), pack-reused 0

which means that everything has gone alright, but when I go to my repository nothing happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type `git branch -r` in your terminal.

this will show your remote branch for the repository.

If it is what you expect to see, you may need to look at your github account, and check "branches". If your remote branch is named something different, no changes will show on the front page and you will have to merge them on github by submitting a PR to yourself.

If that is not what you expect to see, type `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`