# Git: Set up a fetch-only remote?

Tags: git, workflow

When I run `git remote -v` in one of my Git repositories that has a remote(s) configured, I see that each remote has both fetch and push specs:

```
$ git remote -v
<remote-name> ssh://host/path/to/repo (fetch)
<remote-name> ssh://host/path/to/repo (push)
```

For remotes that point to peer developers there's no need to push, and Git will refuse to push to a non-bare repository anyway. Is there any way to configure these remotes as "fetch-only" with no push address or capabilities?

Comment: @sehe, nope, you cannot. With no push URL specified, pushes will use the fetch URL.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

I don't think you can *remove* the push URL, you can only *override* it to be something other than the pull URL. So I think the closest you'll get is something like this:

```
$ git remote set-url --push origin no-pushing
$ git push
fatal: 'no-pushing' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

You are setting the push URL to `no-pushing`, which, as long as you don't have a folder of the same name in your working directory, git will not be able to locate. You are essentially forcing git to use a location that does not exist.

Comment: Yup, you would think "git remote set-url --delete --push .*" would do the trick, but if you delete the push url then it defaults back to the fetch url.

Comment: I personally prefer use of something like '**DISALLOWED**', more visible. But that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares What about **'DONTPUSH'**?! :)

Comment: FYI, after doing this your git config file should look like this: (Note the new **pushurl** option)

[remote "origin"]
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 url = ssh://host/path/to/repo
 pushurl = ssh://host/no-pushing/repo

Comment: Similarly to @Pierre-OlivierVares, I went with `git remote set-url --push origin -- --read-only--` -- note the extra `--` to allow a name with leading dashes.  This felt more readable to me.

Comment: I found that with Git 2.24.0 I had to use DO.NOT.PUSH to avoid "Error: repository no-pushing/REPO doesn't exist".

Comment: @yoyo Is that still the case in 2020 (as of version 2.28.0)? I can't find any documentation either way.

Comment: @Chiramisu sorry, not sure - try it and see?

Comment: This seems more like a workaround. It is a required feature which is missing, to be able to enable/disable pushing to/fetching from a specific repository (though the second one seems useless at first look you might be the only one working on a personal fork so it saves some time when you want to merge latest changes).

Answer (score 29):

Apart from changing the push URL to something invalid (e.g., `git remote set-url --push origin DISABLED`), one can also use the `pre-push` hook.

One quick way to stop `git push` is to symlink `/usr/bin/false` to be the hook:

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/false .git/hooks/pre-push
$ git push
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```

Using a hook allows for more fine-grained control of pushes if desirable. See `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample` for an example of how to prevent pushing work-in-progress commits.

To prevent pushing to a specific branch or to limit pushing to a single branch, this in an example hook:

```sh
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-push
#!/usr/bin/sh

# An example hook script to limit pushing to a single remote.
#
# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If this script exits with a non-zero status nothing will be pushed.

remote="$1"
url="$2"

[[ "$remote" == "origin" ]]
```

A test repo with multiple remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ../gitorigin (fetch)
origin  ../gitorigin (push)
upstream        ../gitupstream (fetch)
upstream        ../gitupstream (push)
```

Pushing to `origin` is allowed:

```
$ git push origin
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 222 bytes | 222.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../gitorigin
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Pushing to any other remote is not allowed:

```
$ git push upstream
error: failed to push some refs to '../gitupstream'
```

Note that the `pre-push` hook script can be modified to, among other things, print a message to stderr saying the push has been disabled.

Comment: Good idea! Without a more elaborate script you'd disable push for all remotes tho.

Comment: @v01pe yes. I've updated the answer to include an example script. It doesn't really need much to filter pushes to a single branch. A shell oneliner would do.

Comment: Nicer more elegant way

Answer (score 6):

The general statement "Git will refuse to push to a non-bare repository" is not true. Git will only refuse to push to a non-bare remote repository if you are attempting to push changes that are on the same branch as the remote repository's checked-out working directory.

This answer gives a simple explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933656/1866402

(I am adding this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to add comments yet)

Comment: a bare repository has no checked-out working directory, by definition.  You can push to a particular branch on it though.,

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a remote set up and just want to prevent yourself from doing something like accidentally pushing directly to `master` or `release/production`, you can prevent this using `git config`.

```sh
# prevent pushing to branch: master
$ git config branch.master.pushRemote no_push

# prevent pushing to branch: release/production
$ git config branch.release/production.pushRemote no_push
```

For the record, `no_push` is not a special name. It's just the name of any nonexistent branch. So you could use `$ git config branch.master.pushRemote create_a_pr_and_do_not_push_directly_to_master` and it would work just fine.

More info: [git-config pushRemote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtpushRemote)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the repository, you can achieve this by making use of permissions. The user who is fetching repository shouldn't have write permissions on master repository.

Comment: If you cannot modify the files, you cannot fetch new changes either.