# git add fetch url to remote

Tags: git, git-remote

In my repo I have the following situation:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  http://repoA/_git/libs (fetch)
origin  http://repoB/libs.git (push)
origin  http://repoA/_git/qpp_libs (push)
```

I want to fetch also from `repoB`. This is how I wanted to achieve this:

```
git remote set-url --add origin http://repoB/libs.git
```

But after running the command above there are still only 3 URLs:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  http://repoA/_git/libs (fetch)
origin  http://repoB/libs.git (push)
origin  http://repoA/_git/qpp_libs (push)
```

How do I add aanother fetch URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you will need a different remote, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747072/will-remote-url-for-fetch-and-push-be-different). I also think it's not a good working pattern to have it otherwise.

So having that in mind, as said [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), you could try

```
git remote add <shortname> <url>
```