# Git: How to configure local branch to fetch from one ref and push to another, by default?

Tags: git

Example: I have a local branch called `mybranch`

I want it to fetch from one remote branch: `remoteToFetch/branchToFetch`

And I want it to push to another remote branch: `remoteToPush/branchToPush`

So when I do `git fetch` and `git push` (on that branch `mybranch`), it fetches and pushes from and to that different references, by default.

```
remoteToFetch/          remoteToPush/
branchToFetch           branchToPush
     \                 /
      \               / 
    git fetch     git push
        \           /
         \         /
           mybranch
```

Is there a way to do that?

##### OBS:

I know [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747275/9761768), but it seems to change all default pushes to one remote only, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
git config branch.mybranch.remote remoteToFetch
git config branch.mybranch.pushRemote remoteToPush
```

See the docs on [`branch.mybranch.remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtremote) and [`pushRemote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtpushRemote).

`git config branch.mybranch.merge refs/heads/branchToFetch` defines the upstream branch. Unfortunately there can be only one upstream branch, you cannot define one branch to fetch and another to push. The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtmerge).

For push try to set [`remote.remoteToPush.push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtpush):

```
git config remote.remoteToPush.push refs/heads/mybranch:refs/remotes/remoteToPush/branchToPush
```

Comment: Thankyou @phd. Just to make the answer more complete: what if I want to specify the default remote branches? I mean: `branchToFetch` and `branchToPush` on the remotes. They don't appear in the command.