# Is there a way to fork a git repository without being able to push to the upstream?

Tags: git, git-fork

I am facing a problem where a fork would be the perfect solution to, except it should not be possible to push changes to the upstream (not even though pull-requests). However, it must be possible to pull changes from the upstream once a while.

Is there a way I can block pushing to the upstream or are there other solutions I can apply?

Comment: It is possible to set the origin to an invalid URL, thus you cannot push to anything. This can be done through `git remote set-url --push origin no_push`. `no_push` is not a valid URL and bam! no pushing

Comment: maybe branch protection rules that restrict everything in combination with a CI that updates the repo could help...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to just disable pushing to any remote. This can be achieved by setting your remote url to something invalid.

```
git remote set-url --push origin no_push
```

`origin` is your remote it will now reference `no_push`. Of course `no_push` is not a valid remote address, thus, it will fail every time you type `git push`.

Once you do want to push, just execute the same command, but specify a valid destination.

There are also other ways you can do that, like using `git hooks` as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336442/6577998).