# Cloning a git repo and keeping the original unchanged

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm trying to expand on a project I previously worked on while keeping the original unchanged. How would I do this? Was told to simply clone the original git repo to another one but it's unclear to me whether once I make changes to the code if this will affect the original repo and project.

Comment: What do you mean you want to expand ? You can type `git clone` to clone a git repository.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you explictly push to the original, no local changes will apply to the original. That is one of the fundamental features of git: Only `push` will actually change a remote repository. Any commit/branch/revert/... is purely local until you distribute those actions via a push (or a pull from the other side).

If you want to make sure that you don't accidentally push to the original, you can [remove the remote](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/removing-a-remote) after you cloned it (of course that also means you won't be able to pull new changes from there until you re-add it).

Alternatively you can keep the remote (so you're able to keep pulling), but configure the push URL to something invalid, as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556155/git-set-up-a-fetch-only-remote).

Answer (score 1):

After *cloning* a repo, there are two distinct repos located at two different places. Nothing you do on any of them will affect the other. The only relation between the two is the *cloned* repo will have one of its remotes set to point to the *original* repo — named `origin`. You can list them with `git remote -v` in the *cloned* repo — `-v` is for `--verbose`, shows the url.

Without further settings, the **only** way the *clone* repo can effect the *original* repo is when you do a `git push` from the *cloned* repo.

You can even cut the tie by removing the `origin` remote from the *cloned* repo with `git remote remove origin`. Now there is no where to push to. But this is usually not what you want. When the *original* repo has changes (fixes, updates, ...), you will mostly want those changes in the *cloned* too. This is when you might do a `git fetch` or `git pull` in the *cloned* repo to bring over those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just clone a repository and then make a new repository from the place you cloned the original one. Then you can clone that new repository somewhere else and you can make changes there. But why do you need 2 repositories? Consider using branches

Answer (score 0):

You can branch your repository in order to keep two independent projects.