# Git: trying to sync local git repo to remote repo

Tags: git

I want to use my local machine for development and use a remote server for staging. I first set up a git repo on my remote server and committed the files, then I cloned that repo locally.

That worked fine, but when I try to push changes to the remote:

```
git push origin master
```

I get the following error:

> remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
> By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match the work tree to HEAD.
>
> You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some other way.
>
> To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked?rq=1

Comment: I'm looking to push files to a web server, so the files need to be present in the web directory. I found a number of solutions for this, but none is as simple and well -explained as Joe Maller's post from almost 6 years ago. http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/