# Git - setting remote repository from existing project with possibility to push further

Tags: git, repository

In my new project I with my team will use Git. We want to have our own remote repository. Form this remote repository we will push code further (we are not the only team working in this project, the project already exists and there exists git repository for that). Unfortunatley we are not jet familar with git. I can make a clone of already existing repository onto remote location. After that the rest of the team will make a copy from the remote location to theirs own computers. Problem is that remote repository should be 'bare' (I'm not sure jet what it means) to allow pushing onto itself. According to best answer here:

[Git push error '[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked/2933656#2933656)

I have to '(...) delete all the files except .git in that folder.' I don't want to loose any data, the project already exists. Besides I not sure how it will working to pushing changes further.

In the same topic there is a nice second answer, which I can use by: creating additional branch on remote repository, but I do not like the idea of creating additional unnecessary existence (new branch).

How all of those repositories should be set? I whould appreciate any explanation with of the solution - as I have written at the beggining - I'm not jet familar with git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question would be why you want an own repository for your team. I guess that the repository 'for all' is the one used for live deployments. So the easiest way for you is to use this repo and pull from it. Create a new branch for your team called e.g. dev and you can create further branches for developing parts of your project. 
For instance if someone of your team has to develop a guestbook he would check out the dev branch you created for your team. Afterwards he would create a new branch called 'guestbook' e.g. The he has to checkout the branch and start developing the app. If it's finished you an merge the branch 'guestbook' into your 'dev' branch to see the results. 
In case your dev branch is working well you can merge it into the masterbranch of the main repository to have the feature live.

If you really want your own repository on a different server you could simply create a new git repository there with git init --bare. Clone or update(fetch/pull) the project to your local computer. Change the remote origin in the .git/config file to your new server and push your project in there.

Hope it helped - but if I were you I'd stick to the branches. Some day you might wanna put the work of your team back into the original project and you will have way more work to accomplish that if you develop on a separate repository on the same project.