# Deciding a Git workflow

Tags: git

I am a Bioinformatician and I'm the only one working on my project. And all my code/scripts have to be stored on the storage space accessible to the cluster nodes (to which I can connect via SFTP and mount via SMB). I am interested in setting up a git repository primarily to:

```
a) keep track of changes
b) cloning repositories to work locally and push later to origin/remote repo
```

I would like to use [sourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to manage my repositories. There are two ways I could think of in establishing this:

1) Use SMB to mount and access the storage space. This allows for me to set up a `bare remote repository` under, say, `$HOME/Git` and I can clone this empty repository to my actual working folder, say, `$HOME/projects` using sourceTree. I suppose its like working locally (once you have mounted the remote storage space). Now I can add files, commit and push to origin (in $HOME/Git). The primary workflow then from both work and home would be to work on the cloned repository under `$HOME/projects` folder. If I know that I'd be going offline for a while and would like to work on it, then, I can clone to my laptop and work locally during this period and then push later.

2) Directly set up a `non-bare` git repository under `$HOME/projects`. Now, create a local repository using SSH method on both my work and home computers and remember to push every time. I would have to work around the problem of `git push error '[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'` by checking out the remote repository creating another branch and pushing to master from the local repository as [outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked).

Do you have a better alternative? (or) Which one would you recommend?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don’t push to non-bare repositories – you are asking for trouble. Set up a central repository that you can access from everywhere that you push and pull from. So: use the first method.

And if you are a git beginner I would strongly recommend using the command line client. That way you will properly learn what’s going on and understand git.