# git error push failed

Tags: windows, git

I get this error when I try to push my change to local repo

```
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you[K
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some[K
remote: error: other way.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set[K
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.[K
To C:\LocalRepositories\CompareDateTime
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'C:\LocalRepositories\CompareDateTime'
```

Comment: You didn't paste the whole thing. Notice the first line of your paste is in the middle of something.

Comment: Look like you have conflicts in the `master` branch. You need to `pull` or `rebase` changes from the remote into your local repo, resolve the conflicts and then `push` the changes.

Comment: What is the return of the command `git status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to push to the checked out branch of your remote, and, by default, you can't.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked) for more help.