# Git Push Error.

Tags: git

I'm new ti Git. I'm trying to push my local changes to central/remote repository. But

```
git push remoteRepo remoteBranch
```

does not working for me. I'm getting this error.

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.26 KiB, done.
Total 5 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To ssh://muneeb@192.168.15.167/home/muneeb/gitRepo_CLI
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://muneeb@192.168.15.167/home/muneeb/gitRepo_CLI'
```

I tried by doing `git config --bool core.bare true`. and delete all files except .git. but no changes in result. geting above mentioned error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change work tree to head, try running:

**git reset --hard**

If you are the only the person working on the project, what you can do is:

**git checkout master 

git push origin +HEAD**

Comment: Can you please explain little more. i'm new to git.

Comment: Explained in detail at: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276907/git-push-receiving-error-refusing-to-update-checked-out-branch) , [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117823/git-push-error-refusing-to-update-checked-out-branch)

Comment: 1+ for your help. thanks. Reason is, on both repo(local and remote) my working branch was same. that's why I was getting that error.