# GIT delete remote branch

Tags: git, gitbucket

I'm trying to **delete** a **remote branch** via:

```
git push origin :dev
```

But the following error appears:

```
remote: Updating references: 100% (1/1)
To ssh://user@git.example.com:29400/user/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@git.example.com:29419/user/project.git'
```

Here's some more detail about the origin:

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://user@git.example.com:29400/user/project.git
  Push  URL: ssh://user@git.example.com:29400/user/project.git
  HEAD branch: dev
  Remote branches:
    dev    tracked
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev    pushes to dev    (up to date)
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

How can I delete this remote dev branch (without direct access to the remote server)?

Comment: Is your remote a personal remote you created ? On another machine ? With the option --bare ?

Comment: Seems your remote repo is a non-bare repo.

Comment: If the repository is `non-bare`, how can I change it to `bare`?

Comment: Seems like you simply need to check out some other branch than the `dev` branch in your remote repo...

Answer (score 0):

Begin deleting your local branch `dev`. After that you will be able to delete the remote one.

```
git branch -d dev
git push origin :dev
```

Comment: Also begin deleting the remote tracking branch with the command `git branch -d -r  origin/dev`

Answer (score 0):

```
git push <remote-name> --delete <branch-name>
```

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: `git config --bool core.bare true`  Looks like it. Plus, check out this page that gives you the answer [step by step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked).