# How do I save/commit/push such that the network has the latest version?

Tags: vb.net, windows, git, visual-studio-2015

How do I save/commit/push such that the network has the latest version?

- I have never used version control before.
- I am new to Visual Studio 2015 (I mainly used VS 2005).
- I am a VB.net developer.
- I am running Windows 10 and have a Windows 2008R2 Server (not AD).
- I need to keep my code private and local (no cloud).
- I will eventually need to have up to 3 developers collaborate with my code.
- I am not a fan of using the command line unless I absolutely have to. (GUI for me).
- I feel that version control should be integrated with Visual Studio.
- I think the code should be stored on the server and a local (working) copy on my machine.
- I believe I would benefit from using Git. (Not GitHub).
- I may also check out Gogs or Bonobo. I hate Java so not (Gitblit)
- I Installed Git on my server - although I'm not sure I needed to do this.
- I have installed it on my local machine.
- I mapped a shared directory (v:)

I have attempted (successfully - I think) to copy my code into a repository and make a few commits.
I thought I was having some success using the Visual Studio 2015 - Built-It / Extension

However, after attempting to use/create a local clone eg C:\Users\My User Name\Source\Repos
Making some changes, Commit All, Then attempting to Push I get the following Error:

"Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details."

Output window says:
"Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Local push doesn't (yet) support pushing to non-bare repos."

I've read but not sure how to apply to VS [Git push error '[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2816369)

PS. Because of my specific set-up/needs I’m struggling to find help. Any tutorial recommendations are welcome.

Sorry if this is too verbose.

Comment: No, I want to know how to use git in Visual Studio 2015! Should I still try elsewhere?

Comment: ah so I should have Cloned, Add code to your repo, Create a topic branch then made changes.

Comment: hmm this is rather frustrating. I'm still unable to do this. I'm missing something just not sure what. Still getting same error. It's not a Team Project. Do I Convert?

Comment: what happen to the first comment?

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems trying to solve this.
One of which was attempting to use the Network Drive as the Master when I Believe the local is the Master.

I am sure that I am to much of a noob with this (even now), however just because it may help someone try bonobo git server. This allowed me to create a LAN based Git repository on windows that I seem to have got to work.

I still think that my problem was trying to find good help that was relevant to what I was trying to do was lacking (or I was looking in the wrong places).