# Why does Git allow pushing to a checked-out branch in an added worktree? How shall I recover?

Tags: git

Git normally refuses pushing to the (single) currently-checked-out branch of a normal, non-`--bare` repository:

> ```
> $ git push upstream master
> ```

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 188 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because ...
```

**This is correct behavior.**  See [Git push error '[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2816369/1256452).

However, on that very same upstream, I have an added worktree with a different branch checked out.  Just before the above error-demonstration, I ran:

```
$ git push upstream pytest
```

and **it succeeded**, when clearly it should not have, for the same reason `master` fails here.  In particular, `receive.denyCurrentBranch` is indeed set to deny current branches.

On that upstream system, `git worktree list` says:

```
$ git worktree list
<path1>     9febb4c [master]
<path2>     406bef8 [pytest]
```

which shows that at least *part* of Git knows that it's checked out.  But then it allowed the push anyway, which leads to two questions:

1. Is this a bug?
2. Now that I am in this mess, how can I recover?

(Additional note: this bug was fixed in Git 2.26, released in March 2020.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it is (obviously) a bug: Git's "is this a current branch" test, in the receive pack code, is using the pre-multiple-work-trees test, which is just to check the main work-tree's `HEAD`.  It needs to be modified to check all work-trees the same way `git worktree list` does.

   (I'm working on two systems connected via VPN where only one of them has a server running at the moment, so I'm using an asymmetric fetch/push model here.)
2. Fortunately, I had no uncommitted work, so recovery was trivial: in the secondary work-tree (on branch `pytest`), just run:

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD
   ```

   which cleans up both the index and work-tree.

   If I were not, however, the easiest trick would be to force a new branch to exist at the previous value of the branch, then check out that branch.  This can be done in one step:

   ```
   git checkout -b tempbranch pytest@{1}
   ```

   The work-tree would now be on a different (pre-`push`) branch, where temporary work can now be committed or stashed or rebased or whatever, and dealt with in the usual way.