# git bare repositories, worktrees and tracking branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bare, git-worktree

I'm working with a code base where I need to be working on several branches at once for different purposes.  So I clone to a bare repository and then set up some worktrees:

```
git clone --bare ssh://git@git.example.com/project/repo repo.git
cd repo.git
git worktree add ../branch-1 branch-1
git worktree add ../branch-2 branch-2
... someone else creates branch-3 and pushes is ...
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* --prune
git worktree add ../branch-3 branch-3
```

Now the `branch-3` worktree isn't set to track the remote tree and trying to make it do so, I get into a horrible mess.

```
$ cd ../branch-3
$ git branch -u origin/branch-3
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/refs/heads/feature/SW-5884-move-database-container-to-alpine-base-2' does not exist
hint: ...<snip>
$ git fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
$ git branch -u origin/branch-3
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'origin/feature/SW-5884-move-database-container-to-alpine-base-2' is not a branch.
```

What's the right magic to get this to work?

Comment: It's not a good idea to add work-trees to `--bare` repositories. I would recommend that you leave the bare repository bare and make a non-bare clone in which to make work-trees. (In particular `--bare` changes the fetch refspec in such a way that any fetch might seriously mess with your in-progress work.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice.  I had assumed that this was how worktrees were supposed to be used; if the repository is non-bare then you end up having to create a dummy branch to sit the repository itself on, because it's not possible to have both the repository and a worktree on the same branch at the same time.  Would you like to put this into an answer I can accept?

Comment: `git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"` fixes everything

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, a side note: if you are going to use `git worktree add` for nontrival periods (more than two weeks at a time), be sure your Git is at least version 2.15.<sup>1</sup>

For your particular purpose I'd recommend *not* using `git clone --bare`.  Instead, use a regular clone, followed by the `git worktree add`s that you intend to do.  You note in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367011/git-bare-repositories-worktrees-and-tracking-branches?noredirect=1#comment95612475_54367011) that:

> ... you end up having to create a dummy branch to sit the repository itself on, because it's not possible to have both the repository and a worktree on the same branch at the same time.

There are several simple workarounds for this:

- Pick one of the N work-trees that you'll add, and use that as the branch in the main work-tree:

  ```
   git checkout -b branch-1 ssh://git@git.example.com/project/repo branch-1
  ```

The drawback is that you now have a special distinguished "main" branch that you cannot just remove at any time—all the other branches depend on it.

- Or, after the clone, use `git checkout --detach` in the work-tree, to get a detached HEAD on the default branch:

  ```
   git clone ssh://git@git.example.com/project/repo repo.git
   cd repo.git
   git checkout --detach
  ```
- The only drawback to this second approach is that the work-tree is full of files, probably a waste of space.  There's a solution to that as well: create a blank commit using the empty tree, and check that out:

  ```
   git clone ssh://git@git.example.com/project/repo repo.git
   cd repo.git
   git checkout $(git commit-tree $(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null) < /dev/null)
  ```

OK, the last one is not exactly *obvious*.  It really is pretty simple though.  The `git hash-object -t tree /dev/null` produces the hash ID of the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) that already exists in every repository.  The `git commit-tree` makes a commit to wrap that empty tree—there isn't one, so we must make one to check it out—and prints out the hash ID of this new commit, and the `git checkout` checks that out as a detached HEAD.  The effect is to empty out our index and work-tree, so that the only thing in the repository work-tree is the `.git` directory.  The empty commit we made is on no branch and has no parent commit (it's a lone root commit) that we will never push anywhere.

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for this is that Git 2.5, where `git worktree` first appeared, has a bug I consider very bad: `git gc` never scans the *added* work-trees' `HEAD` files, nor their index files.  If the added work-trees are always on some branch and never have any `git add`ed but uncommitted work, this never causes any problems.  If uncommitted work does not sit around for at least 14 days, the default prune protection time suffices to keep it from being destroyed.  But if you `git add` some work or commit on a detached HEAD, go on holiday for a month or otherwise leave this added work-tree undisturbed, and then come back to it, *and* a `git gc --auto` ran after that two-week grace period ran out, the files you saved have been destroyed!

This bug was fixed in Git 2.15.

---

#### Why `--bare` goes wrong

The root of the problem here is that `git clone --bare` does *two* things:

- it makes a bare repository (`core.bare` set to `true`) that has no work-tree and does no initial `git checkout`; *and*
- it changes the default `fetch` refspec from `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` to `+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`.

This second item means that there are no `refs/remotes/origin/` names, as you discovered.  That's not easily repaired because of the (mostly hidden / internal) concept of [*refmaps*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch.html#git-fetch---refmapltrefspecgt), which show up very briefly in the `git fetch` documentation (see link).

Worse, it means that `refs/heads/*` will be updated on every `git fetch`.  There is a reason `git worktree add` refuses to create a second work-tree that refers to the *same* branch that is checked out in any existing work-tree, and that is that Git fundamentally assumes that no one will mess with the `refs/heads/name` reference that `HEAD` is attached-to in *this* work-tree.  So even if you did work around the refmap issue, when you run `git fetch` and it updates—or even removes, due to `--prune` and an upstream removal of the same name—the `refs/heads/name` name, the added work-tree's `HEAD` breaks, and the work-tree itself becomes problematic.  (See [Why does Git allow pushing to a checked-out branch in an added worktree? How shall I recover?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41158057/1256452)  Note that this bug was fixed in Git 2.26, released in March 2020.)

There's one other thing you could try, which I have not tested at all, and that is: do the bare clone as you are doing, but then *change the refspec* and re-fetch, and delete all the existing branch names since they have no upstreams set (or, equivalently, set their upstreams):

```
git clone --bare ssh://git@git.example.com/project/repo repo.git
cd repo.git
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
git fetch
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | xargs git branch -d
```

(or replace the `xargs` with `xargs -n1 -I{} git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/{} {}`).

Comment: I like your third option but do you know the windows equivalent of that commit (using /dev/null)? I ran it with git bash but I am developing a build environment for a Windows developer and automating these commands using batch files.

Comment: I don't know how you simulate `/dev/null` on Windows. Ancient DOS had NUL: like CON: and the like (I'm not sure if I am spelling these right), perhaps that works; in any case, I've been told that WIndows has something that does work.

Comment: I tried NUL. Didn't work. I can work around it. I was just surprised when I could not run the command substituting NUL.

Comment: what about `git clone --no-checkout` ?

Comment: @JohanBoulé: `--no-checkout` simply skips the final checkout step. However, in a non-bare repository, Git still creates an initial branch name (in some sense it shouldn't, but `HEAD` is still forced to hold a branch name, so it must). Since the index is literally empty at this point, all files are staged for deletion (!). It's not a great situation.

Comment: @torek I tried the last suggestion you gave when cloning bare. It works as far as my initial testing shows.

Comment: It looks like branches checked out in all worktrees are respected as of Git 2.26: https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ef346482d6d5748861c1aa9d56712e847369b40

Comment: @bb010g: Good find; I added a remark to the linked question as well.

Comment: For Windows the following worked for me:
Although I am unable to encapsulate it into one single command, NUL works.
`git mktree <NUL` gives you the hash of the empty tree. Copy it.
`git commit-tree YOUR_HASH_GOES_HERE <NUL` will make that commit. It will output that commit hash - it is different from the tree hash. Copy it.
`git checkout THE_2ND_HASH_GOES_HERE` will finally checkout the commit.

Comment: This works so well that now one of the first things I do when setting up a new development machine is to create `~/bin/git-make-bare` which does your third option.

Answer (score 11):

I thing there is a very simplest way;

*1. clone the repo without checkout (no waste space)*

```
git clone --no-checkout ssh://git@git.example.com/project/repo repo.git
```

*2. go to the repo*

```
cd repo.git
```

*3. create a dummy branch to have the possibility to create a worktree on each existing one*

```
git switch -c dummy
```

*4. Now create your worktree as you want*

```
git worktree add branch-1
```

*or*

```
git worktree add pathtobr1 branch-1
```

That's all. It is clean, easy without wasting space

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `--no-checkout`.  Is it new?

Comment: Doesn't it work to just use `git checkout $(git rev-parse HEAD)` to have the clone use a detached HEAD, rather than creating a dummy branch?

Comment: With --no-checkout, HEAD does not exist. I don't like this situation because for some tools, a .git repository without HEAD is not recognised as repository. So, the dummy branch is a low price (actually, it is just put one text line in HEAD ;-) ). So, it is possible to work with one worktree per branch.

Answer (score 5):

I've struggled with this for a long time, never remembering the steps I took to create a bare repo that didn't act like one. Eventually I wrote the following script called `git-clone-bare-for-worktrees` to create bare repos for use with worktrees. It seems to work fairly well, but beware that it isn't doing a lot of error handling.

```sh
#! /bin/env bash
set -e

url=$1
name=${url##*/}

git init --bare "${name}"
cd "${name}"
git config remote.origin.url "$url"
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
git fetch

firstCommit=$(git rev-list --all --max-parents=0 --date-order --reverse | head -n1)
git branch bare-dummy $firstCommit
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/bare-dummy
```

It creates a branch named `bare-dummy` pointing to the first commit in the repo and sets that to `HEAD`, ensuring that all "real" branches are available to be safely checked out in worktrees. Other than that, the repo won't contain any local branches, not even `master` but remote tracking branches will have been created exactly as with a normal, non-bare clone. So just run a quick `git worktree add ../master-worktree master` and you should be up and running.

Comment: That's interesting and useful.  Personally, I've created a `git-make-bare` script which does @torek's third bullet-point in the accepted answer.  My workflow when cloning is then `git clone <repo>; cd repo; git make-bare; git worktree add master master`.

Comment: @tom, what do you do about HEAD in the bare repo? My technique of creating a dummy branch off of the first commit is pretty lame, but it's the best I've found so far to keep the bare repo from "hogging" a branch.

Comment: My `git-make-bare` basically does this: `git checkout $(git commit-tree $(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null) < /dev/null)`

Comment: @tom, I remember trying to use a detached HEAD in the bare repo, but if I recall correctly, some worktree operations complained if that was the case (even though I couldn't see why the operation needed a branch). That would have been with a much earlier version of `git worktree` though, so I should probably give that another try.

Comment: It works for me, but then I only use `add` and `prune`.

Comment: I found a slightly different approach and similar script that might be a useful: https://morgan.cugerone.com/blog/workarounds-to-git-worktree-using-bare-repository-and-cannot-fetch-remote-branches/. See also https://github.com/marakim/git-clone-for-worktree

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use the `--separate-git-dir` argument when cloning:

```
$ mkdir project && cd project

$ git clone http://****/wt.git main --separate-git-dir=.git
Cloning into 'main'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), done.

$ git worktree add wt1 b1
Preparing worktree (new branch 'b1')
branch 'b1' set up to track 'origin/b1'.
HEAD is now at 23b2efc Added file

$ ls -a
.  ..  .git  main  wt1
```

The main downside of this technique is that the root `project` directory behaves like an out-of-sync worktree if you attempt to run git commands there:

```
project$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    README.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        main/
        wt1/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But everything else looks to work exactly as intended.

To me this looks like the best compromise of all answers here.