# git commiting error to remote repo in use

Tags: git, ssh, server

I have a remote repo to which I want to push from my local machine via ssh. But because of the error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked) I can't do it without problems, because Iam getting remote errors when the server git suspects that I might damage files there.

```
'[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'
```

The solution mentioned in the other question is to checkout to another branch on the server, that works but is quite annoying. Because I want to have running the master branch there and I don't like to have always switch to another branch on the server before pushing data from my local repo.

How can I solve that?

Comment: checkout to another branch and then push that branch. Then create a [PR](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) and merge to master.

Comment: No, the solution mentioned there is to use a bare repo, not to checkout a different branch. Git is oriented towards pull operations. So add a bare rpo on the server, push to it and pull from it to update the working tree at the server.

Comment: Moreover, you should scan through *all* the answers to that other question. It's a bit unfortunate that none of them are marked accepted, and that the remaining answers show up in essentially random order, but the two key answers mention the `--bare` option and the (new in Git version 2.3) `updateInstead` option.