# Error on push using Git

Tags: git

I am learning how to use git by using terminal.

Following an Youtube video, I was trying to push a change after committed it, but I got this error.

Could you let me know what am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs51E.png)

Comment: The duplicate link seems to have your exact error message, and there are several highly voted answers there.  Try them, and if you still are stuck, then leave a comment here and someone can reopen the question later.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked