# Unable to determine where files are in bare git repository after pushing

Tags: git

I am trying to learn git and created a local directory called `local-repo` with a couple of files. I then initialized git in this directory, added all the files to the staging area, and then committed them to the repository. Next, I cloned the repository in `local-repo` to another directory on my system called `cloned-repo` :  `git clone ./.git ../cloned-repo`

Next, I made some changes to one of the files and attempted to push the files back to the repository in `local repo` but ran into the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked). Based on the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3251126/9666882) answer, I executed `git config --bool core.bare true` in `local-repo` and then deleted all the files in that folder except `.git`. This allowed me to successfully push the repository in `cloned-repo` to `local-repo`:

```
(base) sk@darwin:~/learn_git/cloned-repo$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 336 bytes | 336.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /home/sk/learn_git/local-repo/./.git
   7ceaa95..8951be6  master -> master
```

However, I am unable to understand where the files actually are now, as `local-repo` still  contains only the `.git` directory:

```
(base) sk@darwin:~/learn_git/cloned-repo$ cd ../local-repo/
(base) sk@darwin:~/learn_git/local-repo$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 sk sk 4096 Jun 17 19:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 sk sk 4096 Jun 17 18:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 sk sk 4096 Jun 17 19:36 .git
```

Where the changed files actually pushed from `cloned-repo` to `local-repo` or is my understanding of the process incorrect?

Comment: `.git` is a directory. Your files are in there. https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/git/directory-structure/

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: My mistake...I do realize that .git is a directory. Further, based on the information given in the second link, I could find display the contents of the files using the checksum hashes listed in .git/objects. However, is there a way that I can see the listing of the files in the usual directory structure?

Comment: You mean https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree ?

Comment: Not in a bear repo... you would have to use things like `git ls-tree -r some-branch` and then from object IDs get the content on that branch

Comment: I was able to list the files using `git ls-files`.However, how do I now access the files, that is, open them and work on them?