# git contribute to a project - branch is currently checked out

Tags: git

I have a repository hosted on a server and I want developers to contribute to it.
So I tried to clone the repo to my local machine, edit a file and push it back (all on the master branch) as described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project) in section "Private Small Team".

every time I try to push using `git push origin master` I get an error that says:

> [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)

I have read the error description git is issuing but unsure on how to proceed.

> To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'

Is this safe? Is this the correct way? Why does it happens and is not in the linked example? I am concerned about this sentence mostly:

> By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent

Comment: You probably want to setup your hosted repo on the server as a bare repo instead of a regular repo.

Comment: Since you're reading the Git book, [section 4.2](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) talks about setting up the server.

Comment: @TTT thanks, that was what I was looking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879452/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+branch+is+currently+checked+out

Answer (score 3):

> I am concerned about this sentence mostly:
>
> > By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent

You *should* be concerned about it. You'll be much happier if the repo to which others can contribute directly *is* a `bare` repo.

Comment: am i then able to push from a bare repo to another? isn't a bare repo a "terminal" report where changes are not pushed anywhere else?