# Cannot push Databricks Repo to GitHub Repository

Tags: azure, github, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I want to create an Azure Databricks repository that is linked with my Github repository.

This is what I did:

1. Create new GitHub repository with Readme.md
2. Create authentication token and add it to Databricks
3. In databricks, enable all-file sync for repositories
4. Clone the repository into Databricks > Repo > My Username
5. Pull (this works fine)

However, when I now add files to my Databricks repo and try to push, I get the following message:

```
Error pushing: Remote ref update was rejected. Make sure you have write access to this remote repository.
```

Same error when I try it on a newly created branch.

Does anyone know what could cause this error?

My authentication token has the rights `repo`, `admin:repo_hook` and `delete_repo`

It seems that I followed the [Azure Databricks instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/repos#limitations-and-faq) 1:1, yet it does not work.

Comment: Please re-check that you set Github user name token via user settings & it's assigned to Github, not Github Enterprise. I'm using that integration regularly, and it just works

Comment: @AlexOtt I have tried that, but still get the same error. Also created a new, empty repo, but no luck :/

Comment: @AlexOtt We had this error with one of our users. Msg says its a permission error but we ruled that out (both databricks github app & token method working fine). Found that commit & push multiple notebooks at the same time had this error... push one-by-one working... except for a single notebook file that was the culprit. Found the user was pushing a slackbot token hardcoded in the notebook and github was preventing the push - security violation! Yay Github! Sadly Databricks does not surface the real error. We exported the file and pushed from local machine to discover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is, apparently, to use your GitHub username instead of e-mail.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to resolve this? Where should we use username instead of email? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully push `.py` file from Azure databricks to git with same access permissions given in question. I followed [this](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/github-version-control.html) documentation.
[image]

[image]

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos#enable-support-for-arbitrary-files-in-databricks-repos) For non-notebook files in Databricks Repos, you must be running Databricks Runtime 8.4 or above.

**Enable support for arbitrary files in Databricks Repos:**

Files in Repos lets you sync any type of file, such as `.py` files, data files in `.csv` or `.json` format, or `.yaml` configuration files. You can import and read these files within a Databricks repo. You can also view and edit plain text files in the UI.

If support for this feature is not enabled, you will still see non-notebook files in your repo, but you will not be able to work with them.
Also refer this [SO question and its answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked)

Comment: Thank you for trying it out. Sad that it doesn't want to work for me :/ Could there be any specific rights required outside of GitHub and DataBricks Resource Group?

Comment: Have you tried with .py, .csv or .json file types ?