# anything wrong using to use in a peer-to-peer-Fashion?

Tags: git, repository, p2p

*foreword ;-) : Most people (including me) work with git in a client-server mindset I think („there's this remote repo on the dedicated server, from which you pull and push and not touch otherwise...“) I recall however, that `git` is basically absolute peer-to-peer, there is not truly a central server.*

So, here's my question:

**Are there any problems to have one git repo my machine (`~/frank/repo`), and one on my “household” fileshare (`smb://myshare/somewhere`) connecting them mutually to each other as remote repo *and* work on either one?**

- The benefit being, that at home several PCs in the LAN could directly work on that fileshare server and/while when I am on the road, I will work on my laptop.
- Doing the pulling/rebasing next time I hit home. So yeah, neither side can push, only commit while away, but not a problem for me.
- I simply want to avoid a third git repository (the classic „server“).
- both btw being “non-bare” repos (as in working repos), not running a git server/daemon on any port. Truly just a fileshare...

**purpose:**

I am not doing source code work in this scenario, only „document shuffling“, so now branching or major merge conflicts to be expected. But I do want to have some basic versioning and security against accidental deletion, and a bit of journaling info (who added when what), thus `rsync`, `xcopy`, will not suit my needs...

---

I have some past experience with a local *bare* repo I used to add as second remote (besides github), to push against when trying out things. No server/daemon/thread involved back then, too. The only thing I am essentially about to change is to use a „non-bare“ this time and also work in there,to)

Comment: This can work; I've done it. But I use ssh URLs to connect one machine to another, not a SMB file system. SMB requires extensions to support POSIX semantics (see https://www.samba.org/samba/CIFS_POSIX_extensions.html) and Git somewhat depends on POSIX semantics. Fortunately it seems most systems have these extensions by default (see link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't push to a checked-out branch of a non-bare repository. But if you use different branches on each side, and sync them when needed, it can be possible I think.

Comment: "*…you can't push to a checked-out branch of a non-bare repository…*" You can but you have to prepare the receiving repository: [`git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28383598/7976758) and [`push-to-checkout` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_push_to_checkout).

Answer (score 1):

I, well, looked rather thoroughly into the issue. @phd and @Özgür-murat-sağdıçoğlu gave great hints,.`receive.denyCurrentBranch` is the key!

A good recipe to build up a „tandem repo“ (just two wheels, both usable :) and sync the two without manual intervention.

(**Note:** None of this is suitable for any source code work, just for keeping a mostly growing tree of e.g. scanned documents in exactly two places...)

### creation

```bash
A) "Local" on Laptop ( "server" this is pushed to, itself cannot push (no reamote))

mkcd /home/frank/docs
git init --initial-branch=master --shared=all

# the most important thing! ↓↓↓
git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead

# (you could also take just any other file)
code -r .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 0


B) "Share"

cd /share/docs
git clone /home/frank/docs .
# ↑ doing it like this and in this order saves the add remote, etc connecting pains
```

### syncing

```bash
cd $localDir
git add . && git commit -m ""
(no pushing possible here)

cd $shareDir
git add . && git commit -m ""
git pull --rebase -X theirs
git push
```

(yes, you could wash away changes on local by this, but they are preserved with the first commit hence restorable, if need be.)

The whole sync thing also goes nicely into a `git` alias like `git sync`.

---

Adding some sanity checks and smoke testing, this is my [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for a fully unattend `git sync`:

```bash
# backup of final stable version, including prependd commit comment
# usage:
#       git sync
#       git sync Some stuff going on here
#       git sync 'This+that with special chars like plus'
#
# must be called from within repo, but doesn't matter which side
[alias]
  share = "!                                                                             \
    fail() {                                                                             \
      echo \"\\e[91;48;5;52mfail: $1 ✗✗✗\\e[0m – exiting.\"; exit;                       \
    };                                                                                   \
    addAndCommit() {                                                                     \
      git add .;                                                                         \
      git status;                                                                        \
      [ $? -eq 0 ] || fail 'git status not 0';                                           \
      message=\"$1: $(git status --porcelain | wc -l) Files: \";                         \
      message=\"$message$(git status --porcelain |  sed -re 's/^\\s?(M|A)\\s\\s?/\\1 /'  \
      | awk '{ printf(\"%s, \", $0) }'| cut -c -120)\";                                  \
      git commit -m \"$message\";                                                        \
    };                                                                                   \
                                                                                         \
                                                                                         \
    f() {                                                                                \
    _local='/home/frank/docs';                                                           \
    _share='/share/docs';                                                                \
    local message='';                                                                    \
                                                                                         \
    [ -z \"${1}\" ] || message=\"$1: \";                                                 \
    echo \"\ndir and sanity checks -----------------------------\";                      \
                                                                                         \
    [ -f $_share/.gitalias ] || fail 'smoke test failed: $_share/.gitalias';             \
    [ -f $_share/docsnotes.md ] || fail 'smoke test failed: $_share/docsnotes.md';       \
    [ -f $_local/.gitalias ] || fail 'smoke test failed: $_local/.gitalias';             \
    [ -f $_local/docsnotes.md ] || fail 'smoke test failed local : $_local/docsnotes.md';\
                                                                                         \
    echo \"\nLOCAL part $(pwd) ---------------------------------\";                      \
    echo \"${message}LOCAL changes\" ;                                                   \
    cd $_local;                                                                          \
    addAndCommit \"${message}LOCAL changes\";                                            \
                                                                                         \
    echo \"\nSHARE part $(pwd) ---------------------------------\";                      \
    cd $_share;                                                                          \
    addAndCommit \"${message}SHARE changes\";                                            \
    git pull --rebase -X theirs --autostash;                                             \
    git push;                                                                            \
    echo \"\n\\e[92mdone\\e[0m\";                                                        \
  }; f \"$*\""
```