# Using a local clone of a local repository, push to the repository

Tags: git

I am running a Linux box, with git installed.  There is no git server in operation.

I am using two portable hard drives.  One for work in progress coding, and one for git vcs.

I can clone from the repo just fine.

All pushes however resort in errors.

Example:

Me@myhost ~/repo: git clone /mnt/repo

Works just fine, but from the same location

git push /mnt/repo

Gives a long msg about pushing to head or master.

I assume I can add something to repo config in /mnt/repo, but have no idea what to add.

Any help?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git push origin` or whatever it named the remote when you cloned?

Comment: What is the message? Is it a warning or an error?

Comment: Show the exact command and output.

Comment: @phil no, repositories can be specified as URLs, or paths it doesn't have to be a remote name

Comment: Is the directory at `/mnt/repo` a bare repository or a working tree with a repository (subdirectory `.git`)? In the second case you need to allow to push to non-bare repo: see answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2816369/7976758

Comment: @phd - working tree.  Checking your link now.

Comment: @j6t and elpie - the whole building is air gapped.   Zero external connects.  Getting the msg will need me to photo it.  Afaik can't post pics here.  Is a canned response from git.  Warning in nature I think.

Comment: @all it is exactly the msg in in phd's link.

Comment: @phd - bingo.  But the msg makes no sense to me.  And which config mod would be the correct one?  I'm new to git as hosted, usually just clone from a source.

Comment: The best solution is to use a bare repository. The second best is to push to a non-checked-out branch. The 3rd one is to try `git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28383598/7976758

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to specify what branch you are pushing, onto what branch. Try

```
git push /mnt/repo master
```

This will push master branch onto master branch. For other configurations type `man git-push` and read about the refspec parameter.

If you want to be able to run `git push` bare, then you can set up an upstream branch for your current branch. This will allow Git to remember the repository and branch you want to push to by default.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=/mnt/repo/master
```

Then simply `git push`.