# I do not understand git remote add

Tags: linux, git, ssh, config, raspbian

Not sure if I should be raising a new question but it is related to my previous question.

I want to create a new folder/repo on the remote server. This is in case I start a new project on my windows machine that does not yet exist and then want to push it to remote.

1. I created a new folder locally and then used git init.
2. Create a new text file in that local folder.
3. `git commit -m "first commit"`
4. `git remote add origin username@hostIPaddress:/home/username/new/repo`
5. `git remote -v`. At this point it lists what I want to create.
6. `git push --set-upstream origin master`

and I get an error saying

```
fatal: '/home/username/new/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does this mean I have to create a new directory manually on the remote server first?

This remote server is on the local network.

I tried git clone instead too as suggested by other answers but it still results in same error. Nearly every answer I found uses what I did above or a version of it. What am I doing wrong? Can you not create a completely new folder on remote?

Learning git and creating new folder on remote server

Comment: "*Does this mean I have to create a new directory manually on the remote server first?*" Not only that — if you gonna push to it you should initialize it as a **bare** repository.

Comment: That's not a requirement.... I use non-bare repos and I push to them (so that I can then checkout/_continue working_ on that other box or what not).... not saying it's a bad idea to setup bare repos if you mean to push to them.... what I mean is that it depends on what you intend to use them for.

Comment: If you go to the _server_, to that specific directory (`/home/username/new/repo`), and run `git status`, does it work fine?

Comment: no it does not because /home/username/new/repo on remote raspberry/git server does not yet exist. I want to create it using my windows machine and add to it the code/project which is only on my windows machine currently.

Comment: Oh, ok.... you _can't_ do that *from the client*.... not with git, that is. You need to setup the repo form inside the server with `git init /home/username/new/repo`  and you should consider if you want to have a _bare_ repo there, as @phd noticed.

Comment: ok thank you that answers the question then. So if I ever start work on something on the windows pc then I need to manually copy all the files to remote/raspberry server and then do git init --bare in that folder?

Comment: @eftshift0 Then you'll need to explain to the user why `git push` doesn't work.

Comment: Nope. You init the repo in the raspberry, then you should be able to do operations like pull/push against it.... _but_ if it is _not_ a bare repo, there are some restrictions over what you can push, for example. You won't be able to push into a branch that is checked out on that repo... But once you push into a branch, if you go to the raspberry and checkout that branch, it's *maaaagic* and you get what you pushed into the branch on the working tree _without_ having to copy files around

Comment: @phd I can for foresee that question coming from afar. No worries, it's all fine.

Comment: @eftshift0 Ok, let's wait for the second push! ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, you got a point. :-D

Comment: Actually, you might get trouble in the _first_ push if you try to push into the default branch of an empty repo..... Then you will face the problem in the second push.... Both roadblocks will leave good lasting knowledge once you are able to go over them.... Is there a more interesting way to learn stuff?

Comment: @phd " Then you'll need to explain to the user why git push doesn't work" I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: Git is intended for pull-based workflow. You push to a bare repository and pull from it to non-bare repos. Pushing to a non-bare repository could (and often does) lead to problems and error like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked