# Git remote clone failed, but succeed on local machine

Tags: git, gitstack

I have setup GitStack on remote server. Now I want to clone the repository to local machine, but it failed.

Server Environment:
GitStack-2.2.3,
Git-1.7.10,
Windows 7
Client Environment:
Git-1.7.10
Windows 7

Step 1: If I run the clone command directly on the server, it works,

```
$Git clone http://robin@localhost:8082/TestGit.git
```

Step 2: If I run the same command on a client machine. The clone will fail with the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'TestGit'...  
error: Failed connect to `10.158.169.66:1080;` No error while accessing      `http://robin@10.158.169.66:8082/TestGit.git/info/refs`  
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

My troubleshooting process:
1. As I mentioned above, I have run the same command on server directly, it works.
2. I have checked the TCP port 1080 and 8082. Both of them are enabled. Both Inbound and Outbound rules have been added to firewall
3. The server is accessible since I can browse the repository on client machine through browser.

Question:
I don't know what's the root cause.

Comment: Perhaps your webserver is not listening on the `10.158.169.66` interface but only on `localhost`? Also, try cloning with -v and check the server logs to see if there's anything funny going on.

Comment: you can also try different protocols, maybe it's being quirky. Give a try at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808177/how-can-i-git-clone-from-another-machine?rq=1 for example. the [Git clone](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) is also interesting (section git url)

Comment: Do you have any idea why running :
git clone http://robin@localhost:8082/TestGit.git
redirects you to the port 1080?

Comment: Hi Noufal, I have tried the command ($ git clone http://10.158.169.66:8082/TestGit.git) on server directly. It works well too. Does that means the apache setting works well?