# Clone repository from other user but push to / pull from main server

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-clone

Few users use main server with repository and clone it by:

```
git clone --recursive git@gitsrv:Android/sw/Android.git
```

It last very long (more than a day).

So I've read that I can clone directly from other user if he has already cloned repo from server by:
[How can I 'git clone' from another machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808177/how-can-i-git-clone-from-another-machine)

But I mustn't push into other user repo. I must push to main server. And further pulls must be also done from server not from other user. How to do that?

And by the way: where "gitsrv" is defined (it's a kind of symlink?) ?

Comment: @FirstZero: It is, but the question does not have very good answers.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I removed comment.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily by running `git daemon` on the user machine - assuming it is called `machineA`. Example - `git daemon --base-path=<absolute full path to git repo>`

To clone from that machine - `git clone git://machineA/foo.git`.

For pushing to a different machine, add in a remote server - `git remote add main ssh://mainServer/foo.git` and then push using `git push -u main master`

Remove reference to machineA by `git remote remove origin`. Assuming that your remote server is named `origin`. If you are not sure of the name you can check by running `git remote -v`, that will list the reference name and the URL.

If you want to keep the name `origin`, just set the url by running `git remote set-url origin ssh://mainServer/foo.git`

Comment: Sounds about right, except `git:` protocol is not used for pushing, so it would be better to have `ssh:` or `https:` URL example there.